# Update DATEADD with nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am stuck with a table that has a column, [Renewal] that was set as a nvarchar(255),null. Not my handiwork and I cant change it. I now need to use this column in a calculation. Below as close as I can get with doing it in one statement but I cant get past the "incorrect syntax near..." error after the ELSE statement. If it ran into an issue trying to CAST as INT I would want it to continue with the rest of the records and not hose the whole query. I suppose I could add an additional column thats INT, not null and write an update statement to run prior to this but I fear I would run to the same issue. I am more UI guy than SQL guy, any suggestions? It would run on SQL Server 2008R. Thank you in advance

```
  UPDATE C
  SET [ExpirationDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, 

     (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(C.Renewal)= 1 
           THEN CAST(C.Renewal AS INT)
           ELSE 0)

  , [ExpirationDate])
  FROM dbo.MyTable C 
  WHERE C.MyCondition = 'True'
```

Comment: You are missing the word END.  Google proper SQL Server CASE WHEN syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `END` in `CASE` statement

```
UPDATE C
SET    [ExpirationDate] = Dateadd(MONTH, ( CASE
                                             WHEN Isnumeric(C.Renewal) = 1 THEN Cast(C.Renewal AS INT)
                                             ELSE 0
                                           END ), [ExpirationDate])
FROM   dbo.MyTable C
WHERE  C.MyCondition = 'True'
```

Filter the records with only `numeric` values and apply `DATEADD` function instead of adding `0` months

Also `ISNUMERIC` is not preferred. `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 if the string can be converted to any one of ints, numeric/decimal, float, or money. 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302466/isnumeric-returns-true-for-and

```
  UPDATE C
  SET [ExpirationDate] = DATEADD(MONTH,CAST(C.Renewal AS INT), [ExpirationDate])
  FROM dbo.MyTable C 
  WHERE C.MyCondition = 'True'
  AND C.Renewal NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: extra points (if I could) for pointing out the frailties of using ISNUMERIC :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be more straightforward.

```
UPDATE C
SET [ExpirationDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(c.Renewal AS INT), [ExpirationDate])
FROM dbo.MyTable C 
WHERE C.MyCondition = 'True'  
AND ISNUMERIC(c.Renewal) = 1
```